# A curious Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I would like to prove this inequality:

$\forall \xi, \xi' \in \mathbb{R}^n$   $ \bigl||\xi|^s-|\xi'|^s\bigr| \leq s \max(1,2^{s-2})(|\xi -\xi'|^s+|\xi'|^{s-1}|\xi -\xi'|)$

where $s>1$.

What is the idea to show this inequality?

Comment: This is not functional analysis.

Comment: @Integral Indeed, it isn't. I retagged it. (Though it might be *useful* in functional analysis.)

Comment: I don't have the time to try it, but here is what I would try first, if I did: Put $\xi_t=t\xi+(1-t)\xi'$, differentiate $|\xi_t|$ wrt $t$, and look for an upper bound on this derivative.

Comment: I'm going to try your idea.